# Disable the default constructor of a standard class in C++

Tags: c++

Is there a way to disable the use of the default constructor of a standard class in C++?

For example, I would like to disable the use of the default constructor of `std::optional<T>`, so that a team member must explicitly specify whether the object is constructed with `nullopt` or a value throughout the codebase.

Other than writing a script to check that, is there a solution that the C++ language provide?

Comment: No, there's nothing in C++ for this. C++ simply doesn't work this way, on a fundamental level. Once a class is defined, it's game over. You don't get a do-over, and change the class in any way.

Comment: Writing a script seems suboptimal. Writing a `clang-tidy` check would be better.

Comment: The longer I think about it, why would you even want to do this? A default initialized optional will not contain a valid value. I think it is more important that code can use standard C++ out  of the box. And that a code base compiles without any warnings (treat warnings as errors) has enough unit tests and static code quality checks. AND to train your team to understand what all these tests do and why they should not revert to "tool satisfaction".

Comment: @PepijnKramer This is most for maintainability. I only used `optional` as an example. There are other things like `variant`, `expected` that would benefit from this. Of course this is subjective, but a project is free to set its own rules and maintain its own consistencies and I think the requirement is within a reasonable range. For an extreme example, would you allow your team member to subject every if clause with goto? This is only an extreme example, but you see the point: There is a wide reasonable range for each project to decide what C++ features are acceptable.

Comment: I understood  your goal is for deveopers to avoid making mistakes (I have 20+ years of experience in technically managing teams). The thing is engineers are so "clever" in finding ways to either come up with things you didn't think of or subverting checks you added. We ended up with : "Treat warnings as errors", "Unit tests + Code coverage", "Static code analysis (Tiobe TICS)", "Some checkin rules in for git"  and using as much standard "C++/Standard library types as possible" ... all these things can be configured from commercially available tools.

Comment: By using as much standard C++ as possible, it reduces the learning curve for new developers to understand the code and they are productive sooner (each non-standard approach however well intended adds learning time). But sure in the end you should find a way that fits your code base/developer team.